# Disitinct Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

To get Distinct values, I need an IEnumerable.

```
var results = gridData.Select(r => r.ExplicitColumnName).Distinct();
```

To decide the column name at run time, I need to use an IQueryable as required by System.Linq.Dynamic.

```
var results = gridData.AsQueryable().Select(columnNameIsInThisVar);
```

I want my method to return json so figured List of string and then load that into a JsonResult.  But I'm having problems getting both distinct values and run-time flexibility on column.

So I guess my question is, in LINQ, how do I do this?

```
List<string> results = $"select distinct {columnName} from ridiculous_table_with_100_columns";
```

*Update 1*

As per comments, I've now installed dynamic Linq as a nuget package but I still can't convert to List.

```
filterValues = gridData.AsQueryable().Select(columnName).Distinct();
```

Which gets me a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: By adding `Distinct` at the end (after `Select`)? Dynamic LINQ defines `Distinct` on `IQueryable`.

Comment: Dynamic Linq doesn't provide a Distinct method.  After the select, an IQueryable is returned.  It needs to be converted to IEnumerable but I can't think of a way to do that without building it manually by iterating over the IQueryable, in which case I might just as well filter out the duplicates myself.

Comment: I see `public static IQueryable Distinct(this IQueryable source);` inside `System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable`.

Comment: Aaah.  I got my Dynamic.cs from the CSharpSamples zip as it was linked from an old blog entry from ScottGu.  A quick google revealed it's now available as a nuget package and this one _does_ have the Distinct method.  My bad.  Thanks for the nudge :-)

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :)

Comment: The return value from `Distinct()` is another `IQueryable`, you need to evaluate the LINQ statements. Call `.ToList()` after `Distinct()`, this will evaluate the expression tree into a `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with reflection

```
var results = gridData.Select(r => r.GetType().GetProperty(colName).GetValue(r)).Distinct();
```